# My own method isn't being found by the compiler

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I recently started learning Objective-C and Cocos-2D. I tried to define my own method for automating the creation of sprites.

I added my own class where I'll create other automation methods as well. Anyhow my .h file looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface ActionsClass : CCNode {

  }

@property (nonatomic, strong) CCSprite* createSprite;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCSprite* spriteName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* pngName;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint* spriteCoordinate;

- (CCSprite *)createSprite: (CCSprite *)spriteName: (NSString *)pngName: (CGPoint *)spriteCoordinate;

@end
```

And the .m is:

```
#import "ActionsClass.h"


@implementation ActionsClass

@synthesize createSprite = _createSprite;
@synthesize spriteName = _spriteName;
@synthesize pngName = _pngName;
@synthesize spriteCoordinate = _spriteCoordinate;

- (CCSprite *)createSprite: (CCSprite *)spriteName: (NSString *)pngName: (CGPoint *)spriteCoordinate
{

if (!_createSprite)
{
    _createSprite = [[CCSprite alloc] init];
    _spriteName = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:_pngName];
    _spriteName.position = ccp(_spriteCoordinate->x, _spriteCoordinate->y);
    [self addChild:_spriteName];
}

return _createSprite;
}

@end
```

In the main .m file where I want to call the method:

```
[self createSprite: saif: @"saif.png": ccp(100,100)];
```

This would give the warning that xcode didn't find the instance method **createSprite** and defaults it to **id**

Thanks a lot and sorry if the font or the formatting of the question aren't super neat.

Comment: You can only use `self` as the receiver of a message from within the kind of object that defines the method.  You seem to be saying that you want to call into `ActionsClass` from some other .m file and, if so, you would first need to create an `ActionsClass` object and use it to call `createSprite:`.

Comment: @PhillipMills You're right, I wanna call this `createSprite` into another .m but I'm not entirely sure how to accomplish what you said ;/

Comment: You might want to read something about Objective-C programming, especially objects, before diving in much farther.  (E.g.: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) In addition to what I said above, your code is doing odd things like using `_pngName` without initializing it, returning a value you don't use, and returning a value that's different from one you're initializing.  In other words, I don't see a fix without a better grasp of the basics.

Comment: @PhillipMills my background isn't related to IT or software development which might affect my comprehension, I understand. But I did read a lot and the more I read, the more things become overwhelming. I thought that by starting to write actual code would help me to learn more efficiently.
Anyhow, I just thought that by synthesizing my properties they would be initialized. Isn't `_createSprtie` an acceptable return value for what i'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you want to learn by doing (while reading), I can say good things about "Programming in Objective-C" by Stephen G. Kochan.  There are few programming books I like but his starts from the beginning, has exercises, and is reasonably relevant to real-world development.  (Unfortunately, Amazon tells me the 5th edition won't be out until Dec 4.  How different it will be from the 4th, I don't know.)

Answer (score 1):

Your method declaration is wrong, so you wont be able to call it.

It should be:

```
- (CCSprite *)createSprite:(CCSprite *)spriteName pngName:(NSString *)pngName coord:(CGPoint *)spriteCoordinate;
```

And called like:

```
[self createSprite:someSprite pngName:somePNGName coord:someCoord];
```

Edit: I didn't see that you were trying to call this from another class. To do that you will need to import the ActionsClass header file, and call this method on an instance of ActionsClass, e.g.

```
ActionsClass *actionsClassObject = [[ActionsClass alloc] init];
[actionsClassObject createSprite:someSprite pngName:somePNGName coord:someCoord];
```

Comment: Apart from the colon after `spriteName` in the method signature shouldn't be there.

Comment: @adamjansch but I already tried that before I ask the question and it didn't work.